# DOMPDF omits second line in rendered PDF

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, dompdf

A client of mine had a problem merging two pdf documents. When I looked into it, and ran the PDF file rendered by DOMPDF in a [PDF validator](https://freetoolonline.com/preflight-pdf.html), it outputs:
*1.1: Header Syntax error, Second line must begin with '%' followed by at least 4 bytes greater than 127*

Looking at a valid pdf, this is line 2: %ÓôÌá

The error does not originate from the html, as it occurs even with the default Hello World! example by DOMPDF:

```
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';


// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();
```

Edit: Question is whether there is a way to make Dompdf create the missing line 2?

Should be said that the file can be opened and viewed but error arises when merging with another pdf file.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Added question :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with dompdf, but have you tried not setting the paper size, or saving to a file rather than streaming to the browser?  I find it hard to imagine that the basic "first two lines which are probably constant strings" are wrong at all, much less under some specific circumstances... so I'm just spitballing here.  Is there a more recent version of dompdf?  Open bug about corrupt PDF generation?  This is kinda... *fundamental*.